# Python MySQLdb TypeError with formatting problems

Tags: python, typeerror, mysql-python

I'm new to Python,and recently I'm trying to use MySQLdb module to access to my MySQL server,the code goes like this.

```
import MySQLdb

def convert(value):
    if value.startswith('~'):
        return value.strip('~')
    if not value:
        value='0'
    return float(value)

conn=MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='Timeless418',
        port=3306,db='pythonsql')
curs=conn.cursor()

try:
    curs.execute('drop table food')
except Exception:   
    pass

curs.execute('''
        create table food(
        id          char(40)    primary key,
        description char(200),
        water       float,
        kcal        float,
        protein     float,
        fat         float,
        ash         float,
        carbs       float,
        fiber       float,
        sugar       float
        );
        ''')

query="insert into food values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"#10 value to formatting
for line in open('ABBREV.txt'):
    fields=line.split('^')
    vals=[convert(f) for f in fields[:10]]
    print vals
    curs.execute(query,vals)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

The connection is successful,but when the program trys to run this:

```
curs.execute(query,vals)
```

The system gives this:

```
['06075', 'SOUP,BF BROTH OR BOUILLON,PDR,DRY', 3.27, 213.0, 15.97, 8.89, 54.5, 17.4, 0.0, 16.71]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\MyCodes\Python\13.2.2 import data into db.py", line 39, in <module>
    curs.execute(query,vals)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 184, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Could you tell me why this happens and how to fix it?thanks.

FYI:

some of the original data(ABBREV.txt):

```
~06075~^~SOUP,BF BROTH OR BOUILLON,PDR,DRY~^3.27^213^15.97^8.89^54.50^17.40^0.0^16.71^60^1.00^51^320^446^26000^0.00^0.000^0.459^27.6^0.0^0.070^0.243^4.467^0.300^0.200^32^0^32^32^113.4^1.00^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^2.17^0.0^0^3.2^4.320^3.616^0.332^10^3.6^~1 cube~^6.0^~1 packet~^0
~06076~^~SOUP,BEEF BROTH,CUBED,DRY~^3.30^170^17.30^4.00^59.30^16.10^0.0^14.51^60^2.23^50^225^403^24000^0.21^0.000^0.386^27.6^0.0^0.200^0.240^3.300^0.300^0.200^32^0^32^32^113.4^1.00^1^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0.00^0.0^0^0.0^1.990^1.670^0.160^4^3.6^~1 cube~^^~~^0
```

**Thanks to everybody's help,I have solved this problem**

For the query,I changed it to :

```
    query="insert into food values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"
```

Every `%s` indicates a placeholder

Since one of vals is this:

`['06075', 'SOUP,BF BROTH OR BOUILLON,PDR,DRY', 3.27, 213.0, 15.97, 8.89, 54.5, 17.4, 0.0, 16.71]`

And then execute:

`curs.execute(query,vals)`

It worked! I suppose there is a way that the `execute` will adjust my `vals`,and fill the `query`,for `str` object,it will add `''` to value,and for int or float,it will just put the value in the `query`

**Again,Thanks to everybody.**

Comment: why is your id value a str?

Comment: @scytale Sorry,I don't understand ,you mean a str cannot convert to char(40) or something else?

Comment: what? I mean that your id value shown as passed to the execute statement is `'06075'` which is str, but you've specified your `id` to be `int`

Comment: @scytale I'm confused,`create table food(id          char(40)    primary key....`,I specified `id` to be `char(40)`,Is this wrong?

Comment: sorry  misread the code. never mind.

Comment: at first glance the code looks right. try putting this line before the `execute`: `print query % vals`

Comment: @scytale now I'm using `?` as placeholder,`print query %vals` can't runs well,as I change `query="insert into food values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"` to `query="insert into food values ('%s','%s',%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f);"`,since a list cannot apply to `%`,I use `print query%tuple(vals)`instead,and I got this `insert into food values ('06075','SOUP,BF BROTH OR BOUILLON,PDR,DRY',3.270000,213.000000,15.970000,8.890000,54.500000,17.400000,0.000000,16.710000);`,but still cannot work,this time the Error was `TypeError: float argument required, not str`

Comment: sorry - that's all a bit hard to parse in a comment

Comment: @scytale OK,thanks a lot,I will check my codes and try other way to solve this problem.

Comment: **Don't** format the values yourself into the query like @scytale suggested! Instead look up the expected placeholder in the documentation of the database module you are using. I guess it's not `?` but `%s` regardless of the type of the value. And again: Use the second argument of `execute()` for the values and not the `%` operator!

Comment: I did not suggest that! I suggested putting a print statement which would require a format string

Comment: please read my comment more carefully. it is not my fault if the OP misunderstood